# Azure Maps fuzzy search results are not limited to bounding box

Tags: azure-maps

When I perform a fuzzy search using the Azure Maps REST API, the results are not limited to the bounding box I specify. This makes searching for partial addresses much less useful, since many/most/all of the results are from other states and the relevant results from the specified state are not included in the first 10-20 results.

For example, if I search for "123 Main" and specify a bounding box that covers the state of Louisiana, I should get a half dozen or so point addresses in the results, and all the results should be constrained to the bounding box. (There may be a few results from the edges of surrounding states since the bounding box is a rectangle.) Instead, I get results from Connecticut, Ohio, Massachusetts, and so on that are clearly outside the bounding box.

The documentation clearly states, "You can use the btmRight and topleft parameters to set the bounding box. These parameters restrict the search to a specific area on the map."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-best-practices-for-search#limit-search-results
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/get-search-fuzzy

The test query I am using is:

[https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?subscription-key=[SUBSCRIPTION_KEY]&api-version=1.0&query=123+Main&countrySet=US&idxSet=Addr,PAD,POI,XStr&lat=30.3618&limit=20&lon=-91.1067&typeahead=true&topLeft=33.019457,-94.043147&btmRight=28.928609,-88.817017](https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?subscription-key=%5BSUBSCRIPTION_KEY%5D&api-version=1.0&query=123+Main&countrySet=US&idxSet=Addr,PAD,POI,XStr&lat=30.3618&limit=20&lon=-91.1067&typeahead=true&topLeft=33.019457,-94.043147&btmRight=28.928609,-88.817017)

Am I doing something wrong? How do I limit the search results to the bounding box?

Comment: Duplicate of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1154955/index.html.

Answer (score -1):

The bounding box is meant to help influence the relevance of the results and is not a filter.

Comment: I think you're confusing the bounding box with the lat and lon parameters. From the docs: "To *influence* the area of relevance for the results, define the lat and lon coordinate parameters." "You can use the btmRight and topleft parameters to set the bounding box. These parameters *restrict* the search to a specific area on the map." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-best-practices-for-search#limit-search-results

Comment: I'm fairly certain the docs are inaccurate. The bounding box is meant to add weight, but not be a hard filter, unless it is really small. That's how it works in most platforms and how it works in Bing Maps (older Microsoft mapping API). I used to be on the Azure Maps team and that doc always bugged me and I have logged it as a doc bug with that engineering team a while back.